# Stopping an .mp3 From Playing when Page Loads

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to easily set a simple HTML embed tag to NOT play the file when it's ready?

```
<embed src="Audio/WRECK2.mp3" width="280" height="75" ></embed>
```

It's obviously annoying when the page loads and it starts blaring in their ear without warning...

I looked into jPlayer, but it's way overkill for this single file I'd like to have on my website.

***UPDATE***

I've now tried the following because the autostart="false" doesn't seem to work properly.  I got this suggestion from multiple places, but it still doesn't work...

```
<object width="280" height="75">
<param name="autoplay" value="false">

<embed src="Audio/WRECK2.mp3" width="280" height="75" autoplay="false" controller="false">
</embed>
</object>
```

Comment: If my memory is good you can add this attribute to your `embed`: `autostart="false"`

Comment: Thanks morgul... I've been searching this thoroughly, and it seems that Google Chrome has an issue interpreting that and it still doesn't work.  I've even tried using an object which so many people suggest, still no luck.

Comment: I assume you don't want autoplay. That's Ok - so it means for me, you will probably have button to switch music on? right? If so - why not just use **audio tag**, which works perfectly, of course except some annoying old browsers :) ? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_autoplay.asp

Answer (score 0):

Play Audio

```
var clicked = false, play = document.getElementById("play");
play.IS_CLICKED = false;
play.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(!this.IS_CLICKED) {
      audio = document.createElement('embed');
      audio.setAttribute('src','Audio/WRECK2.mp3');
      audio.setAttribute('width', 280);
      audio.setAttribute('height',75); 
      document.body.appendChild(audio);
      this.IS_CLICKED = true;
    } 
});
```

Comment: Am I supposed to just set any element id to 'play'?  Not working... Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'IS_CLICKED' of null index.html:165
(anonymous function)

Comment: @Bonedancer make sure this script is right before closing body tag

Answer (score 0):

Eugene P deserves credit for bringing this up... I'm not exactly sure why I wasn't aware that HTML had an audio tag, but this worked perfectly.

```
<audio controls preload>
<source src="Audio/WRECK2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```

There are a handful of options that you can use along with controls & preload, and you can find them all [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp)!

Comment: Don't forget that the audio tag do not work on older browser like IE8. Unfortunately, this browser is still used  lot, but the <code>audio</code> tag is a good choice if you dont care about those shi**y(sorry older) browser :).